# DCEF PDF plugin

Tags: delphi, plugins, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm using DCEF (Chromium Embedded), version 1 not DCEF3, in a Delphi project.
I have some problems with PDF plugin, sometimes it doesn't open documents...
Is it possible to update the PDF plugin of DCEF ? 
Is it integrated in DCEF framework or is it the plugin of system's Chromium ?

Comment: What "PDF Plugin" are you talking about? What has Google told you?

Comment: CEF [`does not have a built-in PDF viewer`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12584/why-doesnt-chromium-have-chrome-pdf-viewer-plugin). So the PDF files are opened by some plugin that you have installed. In my case it's the Foxit Reader's one, but after downloading a file CEF shows a blank screen. To get plugin info you can [`run this`](http://pastebin.com/1UUgtRgA).

Comment: @TLama How does Chrome do it? Does it use a proprietary pdf viewer that's not part of Chromium?

Comment: @David, Google Chrome [`comes`](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1060734?hl=en) with PDF viewer, Chromium, its core [`doesn't`](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50852).